# ¿Entity framework debería detectar si un registro ya existe automaticamente?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Creo que con el titulo no se entiende bien. La pregunta es:

Si tengo un Expediente y a ese expediente quiero asignarle nuevos documentos aparte de los que ya tiene, entonces, ¿EF debería omitir los que ya existen al ver que ya tiene una llave primaria asignada? O, ¿debería de agregar una validación?

La pregunta viene porque a mi no me los omite y los vuelve a agregar. Si es normal, diganmelo y borro la pregunta y si no, tengo otra duda (no es como evitar que se repitan).

Estoy estudiando EF por mi cuenta y no he encontrado una respuesta a eso en la web.

La de expediente:

```
public partial class Expediente
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Expediente()
    {
        this.Documentos = new HashSet<Documento>();
    }

    public int idExpediente { get; set; }
    public string NombreExpediente { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public string DuenioExpediente { get; set; }
    public int CantidadDocumento { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
}
```

La de documento:

```
public partial class Documento
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Documento()
    {
        this.Archivo = new HashSet<Archivo>();
    }

    public int idDocumento { get; set; }
    public int idExpediente { get; set; }
    public string NombreDocumento { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Archivo> Archivo { get; set; }
    public virtual Expediente Expediente { get; set; }
}
```

La de archivo:

```
public partial class Archivo
{
    public int idArchivo { get; set; }
    public int idDocumento { get; set; }
    public string NombreImagen { get; set; }
    public byte[] ArchivoImg { get; set; }

    public virtual Documento Documento { get; set; }
}
```

y el context:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Documento> Documento { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Expediente> Expediente { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Archivo> Archivo { get; set; }
}
```

diagrama sql:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

diagrama EF:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos!

donde lleno las listas:

```
if (idExpediente != 0)
        {
            dgvDocumentos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            Doc = DocumentoNG.GetDocumentos(idExpediente);
            bDocumentos = new BindingList<Documento>(Doc);
            dgvDocumentos.DataSource = bDocumentos;
            File = ArchivoNG.GetArchivo(bDocumentos);
            bArchivo = new BindingList<Archivo>(File);
        }
```

donde agrego documentos:

```
if (expediente.idExpediente == 0)
            {
                expediente.Documentos.Add(new Documento { NombreDocumento = txtNomDoc.Text, FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now, Expediente = expediente });

            }
            else
            {
                expediente.Documentos.Add(new Documento { NombreDocumento = txtNomDoc.Text, FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now, idExpediente = idExpediente });
            }
            Doc = expediente.Documentos.ToList();
            dgvDocumentos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            bDocumentos = new BindingList<Documento>(Doc);
            dgvDocumentos.DataSource = bDocumentos;
```

Comment: ¿Puedes volver a poner tus entidades? Pero agrega el código donde con figuras las llaves principales y las relaciones.

Comment: ¿Eso es lo que querías ver @Luis?

Comment: Si, pero también donde indicas cuál propiedad es la llave, y como creas las relaciones, no se si lo hagas con atributos (DataAnnotations) o por medio de la fluent api.

Comment: Disculpa, como no manejo mucho esto, no entiendo lo que me pedís, tengo entendido que la relación se hace mediante las instancias de las clases o de las colecciones en el caso de relaciones de uno a muchos

Comment: Si, se puede hacer por convenciones, pero por ejemplo, la llave primaria debe ser una propiedad llamada "Id", o "nombreclaseId", al menos eso entiendo, yo no uso las convenciones y configuro mejor de forma manual. Veo que tu tienes Idnombreclase, como yo pensaba que no funcionaba al no seguir la convención, por eso pedí el dato de configuración.

Comment: Lo que yo tengo es lo que EF crea automáticamente con Designer from database.

Comment: Entiendo, pensabas que usaste code first, perdona. Entonces en vez de las entidades lo que servirá mas son el diseño de las tablas.

Comment: Por lo que veo, las relaciones están bien, quizás es la forma en la que agregas documentos, ¿podrías, ya por último, poner el método donde agregas documentos al expediente?

Comment: Ahí está el código donde los agrego

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esta solución te sirva.

En vez de:

```
if (expediente.idExpediente == 0)
{
    expediente.Documentos.Add(new Documento { NombreDocumento = txtNomDoc.Text, FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now, Expediente = expediente });
}
else
{
   expediente.Documentos.Add(new Documento { NombreDocumento = txtNomDoc.Text, FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now, idExpediente = idExpediente });
}
```

Prueba a hacer esto:

```
 var newDoc = new Documento 
 { 
     NombreDocumento = txtNomDoc.Text, 
     FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now 
 };

 if (expediente.idExpediente > 0)
 {    
     newDoc.idExpediente = expediente.idExpediente;
     newDoc.Expediente = null;
 }
 else
 {
      newDoc.Expediente = expediente;
 }    

 using(var context = new Entities())
 {
     context.Documents.Add(newDoc);
     context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Aunque tengo duda en la parte "if (expediente.idExpediente == 0)", entiendo que no existe el expediente en la base de datos pues no tiene Id, yo creo que si ese es el caso, podriás probar con:

```
 var newDoc = new Documento 
 { 
     NombreDocumento = txtNomDoc.Text, 
     FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now 
 };

 using(var context = new Entities())
 {
     if (expediente.idExpediente > 0)
     {    
         newDoc.idExpediente = expediente.idExpediente;
         newDoc.Expediente = null;
         context.Documents.Add(newDoc);
     }
     else
     {
         expediente.Documents.Add(newDoc); 
         context.Expedientes.Add(expediente);
     }    

     context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Ojo, está escrito todo de memoria, no he podido probarlo, así que espero funcione.

Comment: Gracias Luis, pero eso aún no me sirve!